# Return value from one Artisan command to another

Tags: php, laravel

I am attempting to call one Artisan (Laravel) command from another command. However, I need to be able to retrieve an array from the command that is called from the "main" command...

i.e

```
// Command 1
public function handle() {
    $returnedValue = $this->call( 'test:command' );

    dump( $returnedValue ); // <-- is 5

}

// Command 2
public function handle() {
    return $this->returnValue();

}

private function returnValue() {
    $val = 5;
    return $val;
}
```

I have looked through the documentation and can't find a way to do this, so I was wondering if there was a way or if I need to re-think my approach.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Artisan Commands don't behave the same way as, for example, Controller functions. They return an `exitCode`, which in my testing was always `0` (couldn't get anything to return if an error is thrown).

Your approach won't work if you try to get a return value, but you can access `\Artisan::output();` to see what exactly is sent by the first artisan command you call.

```
// FirstCommand.php
public function handle(){
  \Artisan::call("second:command");
  if(\Artisan::output() == 1){
    $this->info("This Worked");
  } else {
    $this->error("This Didn't Work");
  }
}
```

**Note:** I used `\Artisan::call()`; there's some apparent differences between the two where using `$this->call()` didn't work as expected, but `\Artisan::call()` did. `$this->call()` sent both `0` and `1` back, regardless of the actual code being executed; not sure what's up there. Tested on Laravel 5.0, which is quite behind the current, so maybe that's it.

```
// SecondCommand.php
public function handle(){
  try {
    $test = 1 / 1;
  } catch (\Exception $ex){
    $this->error("0");
  }

  $this->info("1");
}
```

Running `php artisan first:command` in my console returns:

> $ php artisan first:command
>
> This Worked

Now, if switch the code in `$test` to

```
$test = 1 / 0;
```

I get this in my console:

> $ php artisan first:command
>
> This Didn't Work

So, the rule here I guess is to avoid outputting anything in the second command prior to the result you want to check with `\Artisan::output()`.